# result of child process's exection of some system command can't send to the father process with pipe

Tags: c, redirect, pipe, exec, fork

Maybe this is not a compact title, I am very sorry about that:). I try redirecting stdin/stdout of a child process to its parent process with pipes. The child process execute a system command from the father process input and return the exec result to the father process with a pipe. Here I implemented "cat -n" and "tr /a-z/ /A-Z/", the former works fine, but later haven't return any results. What has caused this? Thank you.

```
#include    <sys/types.h>
#include    <sys/stat.h>
#include    <sys/ipc.h>
#include    <sys/shm.h>
#include    <unistd.h>
#include    <fcntl.h>
#include    <stdio.h>
#include    <stdlib.h>
#include    <errno.h>
#include    <string.h>
#include    <signal.h>
#include    <assert.h>
#include    <sys/sem.h>

#define ERR_EXIT(m) \
     do { \
        perror(m); \
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); \
    }  while( 0)


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    int chi_pipe[2], par_pipe[2];
    if (pipe(chi_pipe) == -1 || pipe(par_pipe) == -1)
        ERR_EXIT("pipe error");

    /* Set O_NONBLOCK flag for the read end (pfd[0]) of the pipe. */
    if (fcntl(chi_pipe[0], F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Call to fcntl failed.\n"); exit(1);
    }

    /* Set O_NONBLOCK flag for the read end (pfd[0]) of the pipe. */
    if (fcntl(chi_pipe[1], F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Call to fcntl failed.\n"); exit(1);
    }     


    pid_t pid;
    pid = fork();
    if (pid == -1)
        ERR_EXIT("fork error");


    if (pid == 0)
    {
        close(chi_pipe[0]); // I don't read in channel 1
        close(par_pipe[1]); // I don't write in channel 2
        dup2(chi_pipe[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(STDIN_FILENO);
        dup2(par_pipe[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        execlp("cat", "cat" , "-n", NULL);
        //execlp("tr", "tr" , "/a-z/", "/A-Z/", NULL);
        sleep(10);
        close(chi_pipe[1]);
        close(par_pipe[0]);
        _exit(0);
    }


    close(par_pipe[0]);
    close(chi_pipe[1]);
    while(1) {
        char input[1024];
        memset(input, 0 , 1024);
        fgets(input, 1024 ,stdin);
        write(par_pipe[1], input, strlen(input));
        char buf[3*1024];
        int count = 0;
        while (count <= 0)
            count=read(chi_pipe[0], buf, 1024*3);
        if (count >= 1)
        {
            printf("buf=%s", buf);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }   
    close(par_pipe[1]);
    close(chi_pipe[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of points:

1. You are suffering from the need to perform non-blocking I/O. You are reading a line from a file, then writing it to a pipe. But there is no guarantee `tr` will conveniently write that line back translated. It might wait for the next line to come in. There is no line discipline in place. What you need to do is read from your file, write to `tr` (if the pipe is not full) and read from `tr` (if bytes are ready) at the same time. Or, more accurately, according to availability of data on the fd (to read) or the availability of space in the pipe (to write). Otherwise you will run into deadlock problems. `tr` isn't writing because it would rather read more first, and it hasn't got `EOF`. You aren't reading from `tr` because it hasn't written yet, so you aren't reading any more from the file either. To do this, you want to use `select()` (or `poll()`).
2. The only way `execlp` will return is if the `exec` fails; in that case you don't want to `exit(0)` as it's necessarily an error.